# Ensuring business rule is not broken with multiple users

Tags: sql, database, domain-driven-design

Suppose I have an order which has order lines and we have a multi-user system where different users can add order lines. Orders are persisted to the database

One business rule is that only 10 order lines can be created for an order.

What are my options to ensure that this rule is not broken? Should I check in memory and apply a lock or do I handle this in the database via procedures?

Comment: How about a (difficult to implement) database constraint? See my contribution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11210474/905902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of options on how you can handle this, including:  triggers, constraints, business rule logic, and data structure.

My preference is the following.  Wrap all inserts/deletes/updates to orderlines in a stored procedure and only give the application layer access to the table through the stored procedure.  This procedure can then enforce this and other business rules.  It would also lock the table for updates while running, so only one user can change the table at any given instant.

A similar approach is to have an insert instead-of trigger on the table.  This would cause the insert to fail when this (and other) business rules fail.  The main concern with this is maintainability.  One trigger on one table is fine.  However, you can end up with a triggering nightmare if you start doing this for multiple tables with cascading inserts/deletes.

You can attempt to do this with a constraint, as one of the comments suggests.  You would definitely want to test this for performance, because you have little control over how the constraint is implemented.

Also, you could have ten orderline columns in the order table.  This would emphatically enforce this rule.  But, there is a cost to having separate columns for each order line and having to deal with issues such as deletes.

Another option, not appropriate in this case, is to enforce the business rule at the application level.  However, with multiple concurrent users, you should be doing this work in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why not do it at the application level by using a critical section/mutex?

Comment: Simply because the database can support this functionality.  Why introduce another element into the development world, when the application is already using a database that can do this?

Comment: I agree with Gordon. Treat SP's as methods on an object, and that the object is itself responsible for maintaining its own state. This is especially true if the DB will be shared over multiple applications, with multiple code bases. ***If***, however, there is only one application, and so only one code base, using ORM or other abstraction layers in that single application is an equally managable pattern for maintain data integrity.  Even so, concurrency of multiple application instances is often *simpler* to handle in the DB itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the worst case, that a large number (aka lots more than 2) of users are all simultaneously attempting to add lines to a single order. (Even worse, assume they’re all trying to add varying numbers of lines, though never more than 10 at a time -- the GUI can control at least that much). This leads to scenarios like:

- A checks is there space for her rows, gets ok
- B checks is there space for his rows, gets ok
- A adds her rows, life is good
- B adds his rows, now there are 11
- All of this took place within less than a tenth of a second

To avoid this, there needs to be some form of central “checkpoint” or regulator where all users go to determine if they can add rows. If they pass the checkpoint, they can add; if the don’t pass, they can’t. The checkpoint must be absolute: once approval is received/assigned, that decision impacts all subsequent checks (i.e. when you check and are granted the 10th line, no one else has previously been granted it, and no one else subsequently will be granted it).

There are several ways to implement this, and they all involve database transactions (ACID properties). Transactions must always be as brief as possible, to avoid blocking or deadlocking with other users. This can be tricky code, and for my money the best way to implement/control the process is via stored procedures (like @Gordon Linoff said).

Comment: Would, but you should consider (actually very common) scenario, where one users starts editing (places lock) and goes to lunch. Better would be use stored procedure with proper locking (you need to lock order itself, not lines). Sure periodic updating of order status (count of lines) on user display would be helpful too.